# how can i extract my ipv4 mac address with tcpdump and sed

Tags: networking, sed

I recently changed my mac address and also whenever doing so, i want to make sure it changed on the network, not only on nmcli or ifconfig

I'm running sudo **tcpdump -i enp2s0 -en** to find my MAC address in tcpdump, but I'm trying to get it where it looks like this with the use of sed

so this

```
18:38:33.808803 5e:b7:19:c3:fe:8e > 58:6d:8f:71:85:ec, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 192.168.1.111.37982 > 172.217.12.66.443: Flags [.], ack 331, win 335, options [nop,nop,TS val 72135922 ecr 127649923], length 0
18:38:33.830092 58:6d:8f:71:85:ee > 5e:b7:19:c3:fe:8c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 143: 172.217.12.66.443 > 192.168.1.111.37980: Flags [P.], seq 1:78, ack 833, win 386, options [nop,nop,TS val 127649986 ecr 72135811], length 77
18:38:33.830123 5e:b7:19:c3:fe:8e > 58:6d:8f:71:85:ec, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 192.168.1.111.37980 > 172.217.12.66.443: Flags [.], ack 78, win 312, options [nop,nop,TS val 72135943 ecr 127649986], length 0
```

turns into this

```
5e:b7:19:c3:fe:8e > 58:6d:8f:71:85:ec - 192.168.1.111.37982 > 172.217.12.66.443
58:6d:8f:71:85:ee > 5e:b7:19:c3:fe:8c - 172.217.12.66.443 > 192.168.1.114
5e:b7:19:c3:fe:8e > 58:6d:8f:71:85:ec - 192.168.1.111.37980 > 172.217.12.66.443
```

and if i can just extract my MAC from it

so far this is what i got, i feel like it can be shrunk

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 -en | sed 's/: Flags.*//g' | sed 's/, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), / - /g' | cut -d" " -f2,3,4,5,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use awk instead

```
awk - F" " '{print $2 $3 $4 $10 $11 $12 }'
```

You say to awk do divide in column by separate the space, and later you say which column have to be printed.

**check again the column** I'm answering you from my mobile and cannot see your post, may I add some think wrong, but the concept is right.

## edited

I check twice now should be right (but check it again anyway)

Comment: The command you wrote works the same without -F " " but they're all bunched together

Comment: `print $2 $3 $4 $10 $11 $12` will concatenate the fields; if you want to separate them by the current `OFS` (a single space, by default) then separate them with commas `print $2,$3,$4,$10,$11,$12`

Comment: Ok! glad to hear that. I was arrive at work just now, sorry if I did not answer you again.